# Questionable blog "content"

Tags: discussion, blog, podcast

Consider the recent blog post ["The last technical interview you’ll ever take"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/08/17/the-last-technical-interview-youll-ever-take/).

It is labeled, honestly, `partner-content`.

What it *really* is is a complete crock of advertising baloney, without a shred of technical detail or any kind of measurable/evaluable evidence. **IMO**.

Also **IMO:** Stack Exchange really ought to police this “content” better – it not only lowers the quality of the blog, but cheapens their brand.

- Speaking only of the posted content.  I haven't bothered listening to the podcast.

But what do other people think?

---

**UPDATE 2022-11-02**

[This newer sponsored post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/11/02/making-location-easier-for-developers-with-new-data-primitives/?cb=1) is the way it *should* be done.  First, instead of obvious hard-sell advertising it contains specific promises of interesting technical stuff to be discussed in the podcast.  And, second, the link in the "Overflow Blog" box on question pages actually says "*sponsored post*" so you *know* before you click:

[image: "The OverflowBlog" showing "sponsored post" link properly]

Comment: You really should listen and then decide if it is *…without a shred of technical detail or any kind of measurable/evaluable evidence*. I gave up at the 8 minute mark because programming and coding is not my field of interest. The "ad" begins around the 7 minute mark.

Comment: 9.15 begins the slightly more technical side. How data is collected, the length of the procedure, why vetting is part of the process. Oh, it's a bit like a dating site, match the company with the job seeker. (10.30) The tagline is "test with us once, apply for ten jobs"

Comment: The _reason_ I didn't listen is _because_ the blog post contained such blatant fact-free fluffing of the product I felt stupider from having read it.  I didn't dare risk the podcast.  I have no objection to product sponsors for SE - I like having SE available and someone has to pay for it and I know it isn't me.  And if the blog post content had contained any useful fact, some evidence, even simply some reason why their AI job-seeker-filter is better than any _other_ (known bad) AI resume filter _that_ would have been fine.  But the blog post introducing the podcast was devoid of information.

Comment: What's worse is, I actually decided to try signing up for the service, only to find out that it's pretty much exclusively focused on web development. There's nothing for C++ programmers, much less anyone who does embedded development. Sure, once you drill all the way through, and choose "Other - I do not fit into the mold" (wording paraphrased), you can specify your language as C++, but then it basically warns you that the service won't work for people who don't use one of their "top 70 hot areas" (again, wording approximate). What an epic disappointment. Well, what did I expect from the blog?

Answer (score 12):

Oh, they've stopped caring about quality a long time ago, and our pleas or constructive feedback to that effect falls on deaf ears.

(Note: I was asked for an opinion and provided one.)

Answer (score 5):

My two cents are below. It is just a personal opinion based on reading several such posts.

The "partner content" blog posts are just kind of premium ads. Nothing more, nothing less.

As such, we should not expect any high quality or even technical accuracy.

They are not bad. They might be useful for some people who are interested in those topics, so I don't think SE should stop posting them altogether.

And keep in mind SE is a business, first of all. If those blog posts save some ads on the sites themselves, that's enough to justify their existence IMO.

> but cheapens their brand

I don't think so. The brand is Q&A site(s), the blog posts are just some additional, and people (hopefully) know it.