# "Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server" is back

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, uploader, regression

Image uploads in posts fail and give the following error message:

> Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server.

Tested on different computers, different connections and different SE sites. 0% success rate.

The same bug [occurred yesterday and was fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382854/image-uploading-fails-with-failed-to-upload-image-an-error-occurred-on-the-ser), but has come up again.

---

Example:

[image]

Comment: Able to reproduce both on the site and in chat.

Comment: Well, the fix does say "There is a chance we'll blip if the server we've routed to goes down or is rotated", so likely that's what happened. Hopefully it will be fixed again after weekend.

Comment: Hopefully sooner @ShadowTheKidWizard. I wonder if paid customers are facing the same issues, cause that would mean there could be a quick fix under their SLA's.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard After weekend? Adding images is an essential tool for me at TeX.SE to show output.

Comment: SE does pay imgur to maintain it - and it seems like the issues are on their end. @Luuklag 'paid' customers  - on teams have their images hosted on SE so they wouldn't be affected.That said - ehhh, While I suspect it'll get fixed sooner, and its 'annoying' it probably can wait for a dev or SRE

Comment: @egreg no, it's not essential. Posting questions and answers, voting, those are the only essential things. People can host images in other places, e.g. imgur.com itself, then link to the image. Of course not ideal, but it works.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek not exactly, from what I understand the problem is with DNS, so it's issue with whichever host imgur are using - it's on them, but not directly.

Comment: Well imgur probably has an SLA, and probably deserve to get smacked with a rolled up newspaper.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard "Posting questions and answers, voting, those are the only essential things. " Pictures of of the output are an essential part in most tex answers. Being able to see the output is often more essential to judge if an answer is what you are looking for than seeing the votes. Using workarounds to upload images will risk the long term value of these answers.

Comment: @sam but as I said, it's possible to host images in different places, that's how people posted images before SE bought imgur internal hosting. So when there is alternative to something, it's not essential, that's my point. (There's no alternative for posting questions and answers, or to voting.)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek imgur are way too big to care for being smacked, that's the problem. Back in the day when Jeff made the deal with them, they were small (and new?) image hosting, having the desire to satisfy their customers. That's just no longer true, like with any company that became too big.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Of course there are alternatives for posting questions and answers, there are plenty of alternative Q&A sites.

Comment: @sam I mean alternatives on the site itself. Sorry for not being clear, and yes, uploading images as whole, over the internet, is indeed essential. But I'm talking only about actions inside Stack Exchange.

Comment: We're investigating again.  I'll update with more info shortly

Comment: @KyleMit just curious, is this really considered "critical" and justifies calling you to work during weekends?

Comment: Ehh, no one's forcing me to be here.  I was working on a SO question (just a normal end-user) and saw some pings and can't help myself.  We do internally grade severity, and interruptions to question asking flow is considered pretty important, although of course not *every* questioner is impacted, just those looking to upload images.

Comment: @KyleMit so you're doing this in your free time, that's... noble. Can't thank you enough, and hope you'll get compensation other than virtual reputation! :D

Comment: @KyleMit Thank you for looking into this. On GD.SE, this kind of bug is highly disruptive to both askers and answerers (and I assume it goes for Photo.SE and other more visually inclined communities)

Comment: @curious indeed I encountered the issue while on GD :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thank you all for the reports and attention.  I genuinely love how much pride and effort the community puts into Stack Exchange.

This has, again, been remediated by a band-aid fix on our web server tier with a manual DNS entry.  Image upload *should be* fully operational at this time.

We still need to investigate why the DNS update didn't work, but are hoping to continue the investigation on Monday unless we experience any additional issues.

As always, thanks for your patience, I'll try to add some additional monitoring, but feel free to ping me in the comments if you see any issues.

Comment: Go enjoy your weekend now!

Comment: Thanks @Luuklag, will do.  Gonna take the dogs for a walk in the woods!

Comment: BTW, are you Kyle East or West? ;)