# Non-space characters following an SE shortlink aren't shown in preview

Tags: bug, markdown-preview, short-links

Example:

[image]

The `:` isn't shown in the preview.

---

You can test yourself with the following:

1. ["Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server" is back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382916/178179): test 1
2. ["Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server" is back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382916/178179fghfgh561f1g6651fbg651dfv) test 2
3. ["Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server" is back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382916/178179:fghfgh561f1g6651fbg651dfv) test 3
4. ["Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server" is back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382916/178179::): test 4

Comment: Related, but opposite, report: [Period (.) after a link renders after the link in preview, but as part of the link in the rendered post, when there are bold/italic markers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367024/period-after-a-link-renders-after-the-link-in-preview-but-as-part-of-the-li)

Comment: I noticed this before with a single period (`.`). It looks like multiple periods after the URL display just fine.

Comment: I'd assume it is because [the colon is considered part of the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2053132/2821954) somehow, thus it's also converted to the title.