# Imgur link fails to render while adding an image in question: "Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server"

Tags: support, asking-questions, images, bug-reports

I have faced this issue 2-3 times. Whenever I paste an Imgur link in an image upload window, it gives an error:

> Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server

[image: Imgur link is not valid in a Stack Overflow post]

Comment: [See also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382854/image-uploading-fails-with-failed-to-upload-image-an-error-occurred-on-the-ser)

Comment: I feel like the error message could be more descriptive :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your link is not an image. It's a webpage. The actual image:

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSNLk.jpg`

However, that image is over 2MiB, so it still won't upload. Try reducing the image first.

However, you don't need to actually upload the image. It's already on Imgur, so can be included directly.

`[![Alt text picture][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSNLk.jpg)`

Original:

[image: Original]

Resized:

[image: Resized]

Comment: Thanks. I just hit grab link from Imgur and that was link not the image.

Comment: Can also paste the link to direct image and imgur will resize it by itself.